# "what characterises, mark or sign"?

Tags: word-choice

While proofreading I came across a sentence like this:

> Assiduous research is ***what characterises*** a true professional.

Instinctively I thought that this sentence would sound better if expressed in this way:

> Assiduous research is ***the mark/the sign of*** a true professional.

Does it read any better, or am I being overcorrect ***again*** ?

Comment: Both sentences are correct. Which one is better will depend on context. Often they would be equally good. In the abstract I prefer the second because the words are slightly simpler, but it is not *my* preferences that matter.

Comment: I am very interested in the preferences of a native, but I do understand that it may be off-topic. However, I am grateful you did share your preference on this context with me!

Comment: Unless you are copy editing, I would not change it. There is absolutely nothing wrong with it.

Comment: "the mark/sign" can refer to something indirectly connected: "A well-thumbed dictionary is the sign of a good lexicographer", "A binful of empty bottles is the sign of a good party". "Characterises" implies a closer relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that all three of your examples overstate the value of research.  For example in the first case I believe it is more correct to say:

> Assiduous research is one characteristic of a true professional.

There are characteristics other than research that are quite important to a professional, especially a true one.

In this case, which of these is better is a matter of taste or style.  All three of your examples mean essentially the same thing.

Comment: You are quite right, I did not think of that. However, in proofreading I have the principle that I must only improve the language without modifying the meaning of the author. But it is a reasonable comment, I will include it as a suggestion!